# Does this sum of two non-commuting projection operators have a purely discrete spectrum?

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces

This question defines two non-commuting self-adjoint projection operators $A$ and $B$ on a separable Hilbert space and asks about the spectral decomposition of their sum, $A+B$.

Consider the Hilbert space of complex-valued functions $\psi(x)$ of a single real variable $x$ with the usual inner product $\langle\psi,\phi\rangle = \int dx\ \psi^*(x)\phi(x)$. Consider these two projection operators $A$ and $B$:

- $A$ projects onto the positive half-space in the original ($x$) representation.
- $B$ projects onto the positive half-space in the Fourier-transformed representation.

Explicitly, define $A$ by
$$
 A\psi(x)=\begin{cases}
  \psi(x)&\text{ if }x > 0 \\
  0 &\text{ otherwise}.
  \end{cases}
$$
Define $B$ by
$$
 B\psi(x)
 =\int_{0}^\infty dp\ \int_{-\infty}^\infty dy\ e^{ip(x-y)}\psi(y).
$$
**Question:** Does the self-adjoint operator $A+B$ have a purely discrete spectrum?

I suspect the answer is no (I suspect the spectrum is purely continuous), but this is just a gut feeling. I'm looking for insights about how to deduce at least qualitative information about the spectrum of this particular operator.

Comment: The question was inspired by this Physics SE post: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/498675